# How to end one-word sentences like "done"?

Tags: punctuation, sentence, periods, sentence-fragments

How do we end one-word sentences? Should there be a full stop or another punctuation mark? or can I just use it without any punctuation mark?

I usually say "Done." in response to emails where I'm requested to do something. For example, when I'm asked to do a translation I would just reply "Translation done!" instead of writing "The translation has been done." is that grammatically correct?

Comment: You called them "sentences,' didn't you? Then they need a terminating punctuation mark, just as any other sentence. Done.

Comment: "Translation done!" is not a one-word sentence. Right?

Comment: Right. I just wanted to take this chance to explain what I really wanted to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Done." is a completely valid and grammatically correct "sentence." Technically a sentence must contain a subject and a verb, but the subject is implied and understood from the preceding discussion.

"Translation done." is not grammatically correct. At this point, I think it would be expected that you have a verb to complete the sentence. You sort of have to commit to one or the other.

After the comments, I'm updating this to explain why *I* would not say "Translation done." I've always been taught that "done," as a past participle, should not occur without an auxiliary verb. The exception provided for one-word sentences is accepted by most. But by adding another word without a verb it becomes a fragment, not a special type of sentence. If you find that acceptable, use it!

To me, "Translation done" is no more correct than the following:

> I done.
>
> It done.
>
> We done.

"Mission accomplished" is a complete sentence, not a fragment.

None of this is to say that the recipient of your email wouldn't understand what you meant. In an office setting, I wouldn't hesitate using "Translation done." But I would do so knowing it was not grammatically correct.

But to your question, you can use any punctuation available to you in normal sentences.

1. Period

   > Done.
2. Exclamation point

   > Mary!
3. Question mark

   > Where?

Comment: What about using just "Translated." instead of "Translation done." or "The request has been completed."? Is it grammatically correct now?

Comment: @Xemnarth "The request has been completed" would be undeniably grammatically correct. I would argue "Translated." is also fine, supposing of course that what was translated can be readily inferred.

Comment: "Translation done!", "Job done" and "Mission accomplished!" are as acceptable as 'Done!", 'Tomorrow' or 'Yes' in the right contexts, as they convey a fact clearly. All are sentence fragments, and do not need to conform to grammatical requirements for sentences proper (though non-standard, outlandish strings should obviously be avoided, as should excessive use).

Comment: "Translation done." is indeed grammatical. Whatsa prob with that? In that case, how is it that *"Done." is a completely valid and grammatically correct "sentence."*?

Comment: @Kris I've updated my answer to explain why I would not use "Translation done." It is a fragment, not a sentence. The exception for one-word sentences does not apply if there is more than one word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Mission accomplished" is a completed sentence, not a fragment. To the extent you're comfortable using sentence fragments, then of course I agree the rules of grammar can be ignored. I use fragments in conversation regularly, but the OP asked if they are grammatically correct. I do not think they are.  Usable? Yes. Correct? No. I've also updated my answer to explain why I would not say "Translation done."

Comment: I don't see a grammatical difference between "Translation done" and "Mission accomplished" (unless the latter is intended to say that the mission has accomplished something).  The former is a compressed version of "The translation is done" and the latter is a compressed version of "The mission is accomplished."

Comment: @andreasblass "done" is not a verb that should stand alone. "Accomplished" can stand alone. If I said "He done." would you know what I meant? And is it grammatically correct? What about "I ran"?

Comment: "He done" looks just about as (un)grammatical to me as "He accomplished."

Comment: Which is why I wouldn't have chosen it as a counter-example. Regardless, if you added an object it would be fine. The same can't be said with "done."

Comment: Screw it. I will just say "Done" or "Translation/task/job completed".

Comment: @ jbonecaL ' "Mission accomplished" is a completed sentence, not a fragment.' is incorrect.

Comment: @AndreasBlass The latter is a compressed version of "The mission has been accomplished" and (without further context) will be heard by many English speakers as more grammatical than "Translation done". "He done" is likewise more comprehensible than "he accomplished" in several dialects, albeit they could be talking about his record of accomplishments.